# Is it possible to mock / stub methods of the same test class with ScalaMock?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, scalamock

With Mockito and other testing frameworks there are usually ways to mock functionality of a method within the test class.  I couldn't seem to get ScalaMock to accept the same way.

```
class A {
 def methodUnderTest()
 def methodUsedInMethodUnderTest()
}
```

Then in the test class I'm:

```
(A.methodUsedInMethodUnderTest _)
.expects.....
a.methodUnderTest shouldEqual ..
```

I know that if you are mocking / stubbing out the class and then calling the same functionality on a real instance this won't work.  But there are workarounds by using mocks for both calls etc.

If this is the wrong approach, what would be the best way to test a method that uses other methods in the same test class?  I thought that decoupling the methods was the best practice.

Thanks!

Comment: What is wrong with standard approach - creating an instance of the mock of type A and mocking methodUsedInMethodUnderTest?

Comment: I don't understand which problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @Ava Yeap, so tried that and seems like that's not possible with the ScalaMock framework it seems.

Comment: @Jasper-M Basically I'm trying to mock a method that's used inside the method I'm trying to test.  But usually workarounds like Ava suggested don't seem to be possible via ScalaMock and was curious if there's a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can create a mock of `A` and then tell ScalaMock to execute the real implementation of `methodUnderTest`.

```scala
val aMock = mock[A]

when(aMock.methodUnderTest).thenCallRealMethod()
when(aMock.methodUsedInMethodUnderTest).thenReturn(someValue)

aMock.methodUnderTest shouldEqual someOtherValue
```

Comment: Ahhhh this could be it! I will test this tomorrow and report back!